# Laravel 5.4... redirect with admin model fails

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have two tables, one for admin the other for users, I have created two models for the same.. The problem is redirecting the admins since it redirects back to the page specified in the handler... anyone who has a better way of redirecting?

Comment: Please read and apply the following instructions [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question! If you improve your question, you improve your chances for us to help you!

Comment: Try to improve your question. You've created Admins and Users tables but how do you Differentiate the user when it comes to session. Do Admin Table has anything to identify if the user is admin or not?